# Convert Google test XML report to HTML (console)

Tags: html, xml, unit-testing, junit, googletest

I need an example (in some console tool) to convert generated gtest XML report to HTML.
A solution mast be without using ant or Maven.

Answer (score 5):

you should use `xslt` to transform `xml` into `html`.

you could use the `xsltproc` tool from the command line under linux. I guess there are equivalent tools for other OSes.

Comment: Don't you need to have a style sheet if you are using xsltproc ti transform xml into html?

Comment: Yep. The commandline tool `xslt` needs also as input an XSLT file (the stylesheet) so as to transform an `xml` file into something else. This is the aim of XSLT. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT

Answer (score 3):

I did it for myself with programming language, which is Python 2.*: https://github.com/burlachenkok/gtest_report

Also this gtest_report supports comparision of 2 or more google test results.

If to be honest it was the prime goal.